# Angular: Mat-Table not updating after Mat-Dialog close

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-dialog

I have a dialog box with a form. After inserting data on clicking save the `HTTP POST` service gets called and data gets inserted in the database.
This dialog component is connected with a parent component where a table (Mat Table) is displayed. This Mat Table gets its data from the `HTTP GET` service called inside `getTableData()` method.
What problem am facing is that upon clicking the `SAVE` button of the dialog (which inserts data and closes the dialog then) the tabled doesn't get updated with the newly inserted value. Below is my code for reference:

**Dialog Component**

```
constructor(private adminService: AdminCategoryService, private fb: FormBuilder, private snackbarService: SnackbarService, public matDialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateCategoryModalComponent>) {}

onSubmit() {
  this.adminService.createExamCategory(this.formdata.value).subscribe(response => {
    if(response.message == 'Duplicate exam category') {
      this.snackbarService.class = 'red-snackbar';
      return this.snackbarService.open('Exam Category Already Present !!');
    }
    this.snackbarService.class = 'green-snackbar';
    this.snackbarService.open('Exam Category Added Successfully');
    this.matDialogRef.close(); // Even after specifying mat-dialog-close in HTML I specified here also for being sure that the dialog closes
  });
}
```

**Dialog HTML**

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
        <button type="submit" mat-flat-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial [disabled]="formdata.invalid">Save</button> // Here the "cdkFocusInitial" is also  throwing a warning
        <button mat-flat-button color="warn" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

**cdkFocusInitial Warning message**

> Element matching '[cdkFocusInitial]' is not focusable. a11y.js:1510

**Parent component ts of the dialog**

```
openDialog() {
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(CreateCategoryModalComponent);
    dialog.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
      this.ngOnInit(); // Firstly here I called "getTableData" then I thought that calling "ngOnInit" as it will refresh the full component.
    });
}

private getTableData() {
  this.adminCategory.getExamCategory().subscribe((reponse: any) => {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.ExamCategoryData = reponse.examCategoryList;
    this.dataSource.data = this.ExamCategoryData;
    this.length = this.ExamCategoryData.length;
  }, error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
} 

ngOnInit() {
  this.columnsToDisplay = ['id', 'examCategoryName', 'isActive', 'Action'];
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ExamCategory>();
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.getTableData();
}
```

Please help where I am facing the issue ? Also after what am seeing is that when the table doesn't get updated if I press the `Cancel` button in the dialog which also has `mat-dialog-close` the table gets refreshed.

**P.S. Sometimes the realtime update of the table is working**